# What is a good database design approach for my Online Quiz Android Application?

Tags: mysql, database-design, erd

I have been working on an Android Online Quiz Application with PHP & MySQL. I know what attributes i need however when designing the relationship it becomes complex and confusing when I analysed it. I do not know if this would be a good database design before I write in MySQL and implement it in my project. See my ERD Below:

[image]

As the design above, I am trying to design that will also work for creating charts with any android chart generation library. I am not sure about this design and I am thinking that I might struggle ending up to redo my database design. Any suggestions for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Under user_question_answer why do you have best_category ?